# SharpLibZip: Add file without path

Tags: compression, sharpziplib

I'm using the following code, using the [SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpziplib.com/) library, to add files to a .zip file, but each file is being stored with its full path.  I need to only store the file, in the 'root' of the .zip file.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Create(zipFilePath))
{
     zipFile.BeginUpdate();
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
          zipFile.Add(file);
     }
     zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

I can't find anything about an option for this in the supplied documentation.  As this is a very popular library, I hope someone reading this may know something.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My solution was to set the `NameTransform` object property of the `ZipFile` to a `ZipNameTransform` with its `TrimPrefix` set to the directory of the file.  This causes the directory part of the entry names, which are full file paths, to be removed.

```
public static void ZipFolderContents(string folderPath, string zipFilePath)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
    using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Create(zipFilePath))
    {
        zipFile.NameTransform = new ZipNameTransform(folderPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            zipFile.BeginUpdate();
            zipFile.Add(file);
            zipFile.CommitUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

What's cool is the the NameTransform property is of type `INameTransform`, allowing customisation of the name transforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After so much struggle I could solved my issue.

Answer (score 12):

How about using [System.IO.Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) combined with the entryName parameter of ZipFile.Add()?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Create(zipFilePath))
{
     zipFile.BeginUpdate();
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
          zipFile.Add(file, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
     }
     zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

Comment: There is no overload with an entryName parameter for ZipFile.Add() when adding a file by name, but I like your thinking.  See my answer below.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the library?  It does have an overload on the file.add

Comment: I am pretty sure there is, at least in the latest version.

Comment: Had the same problem myself today, updated my library to the latest version, used to overload for Add and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN entry for `Directory.GetFiles()` states that *The returned file names are appended to the supplied path parameter.* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), so the strings you are passing to `zipFile.Add()` contain the path.

According to the SharpZipLib documentation, there is an overload of the Add method,

> ```
> public void Add(string fileName, string entryName) 
> Parameters:
>   fileName(String) The name of the file to add.
>   entryName (String) The name to use for the ZipEntry on the Zip file created.
> ```

Try this approach:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Create(zipFilePath))
{
     zipFile.BeginUpdate();
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
          zipFile.Add(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
     }
     zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you exclude the directory from the file path you are adding, the Add method won't find the file.  See my answer below.