# SharpZipLib ZipEntry how can you change the name of a file in the zip?

Tags: c#, encryption, sharpziplib

How do you change the name stored in the zip file?

Also, can this be done when adding the file via:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("path");
zf.BeginUpdate();
zf.Add(filePath);  <-- i would like to also be able to change it when adding
zf.CommitUpdate();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharpLibZip:  Add file without path.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198285/sharplibzip-add-file-without-path)

Comment: The question is similar, but is it the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the `NameTransform` property?

See [SharpLibZip: Add file without path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198285/sharplibzip-add-file-without-path) for an example of usage.

**Update**: Apparently, the latest version of SharpZipLib contains an overload for `Add()` that takes the filename.

Comment: is there an easier way - j/k .. geeze somehow i missed that - thank you :-)